# Work item does not show on TFS Web Backlog

Tags: tfs

I have just added a custom state to the User Story work items in TFS. However, everytime that the work items are in this new custom state they do not appear in the backlog at the web.
Does anyone know how I can have these work items being shown on the web backlog?

Thanks
Ricardo

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to the issue.
Process configuration had to be changed.
Under RequirementsBacklog element the new state needed to be added wht Type="Proposed" as it is not a start and not a end state.

witadmin exportprocessconfig and importprocessconfig were used to update the Project process configuration file.